# Datatype Mismatch in THEN/ELSE expression

Tags: teradata

I am trying to run below query snippet in a Teradata query

```
WHERE  COALESCE(CAST (EXPC_DLVR_TS as date),'2020-12-31') >'2016-11-18'
```

I tried another but similar one

```
WHERE CAST(COALESCE(EXPC_DLVR_TS,'12/31/2020 17:00:00.000000-08:00') as date) >'2016-11-18'
```

For both the queries I am getting below error -

```
Datatype Mismatch in THEN/ELSE expression
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell Teradata that '2020-12-31' is a date, otherwise it thinks it's a string. Just preface it by `DATE`.  It's a good habit to always do that for dates.

```
where COALESCE(CAST (EXPC_DLVR_TS as date),date '2020-12-31') > date '2016-11-18'
```